# Entity.resource error in google drive api call

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api, webhooks

after connected to Google drive, I want to follow user changes.

```
credentials = json.loads(flow.step2_exchange(code).to_json())

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(credentials['access_token']), 'Content-Type': "application/json"}
token_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/startPageToken'

token_resp = requests.get(token_url, headers=headers)
pageToken = json.loads(token_resp.content)['startPageToken']

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/changes/watch?pageToken={}&alt=json'.format(pageToken)
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(credentials['access_token']),}
data = {
    "id": str_tools.random_str(40),
    "type": "web_hook",
    "address": my_url
}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

and I'm receiving this error

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "message": "entity.resource"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "entity.resource"
    }
}
```

What does it means "entity.resource" and how can I fix this error

Thanks.

Comment: I search the internet and I can't find the real meaning or caused by the error `entity.resource`. Usually the error code 400 means that the request you sent to the website server, often something simple like a request to load a web page, was somehow incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it. So try to check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414767) that have that kind of error if it can help you.

Comment: I forgot to add `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`  in the requests header :)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`  in the requests header.